# Return ALL data when making a third Party API Call (limits 1000/call)

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, api, rest

**Problem:** Making a third party API call using Node.JS. API link allows only 1000 users/call. I can retrieve the next 1000 if I pass in the params in the API Call URL`(?firstResult=1001&maxResults=1000&orderBy=NAME&ascending=true)` where to start. Total number of users are about 9500. They don't seem like a lot but then I also need to fetch each user properties. This returns hundreds and thousands of lines of json back.

**What?** I am looking for someone to guide me how to structure this. Do I loop through every 1000 till it reaches max and have it write the JSON data in a file? The third party limits me to 1000/call. Wonder if there is a way around it.

Please provide an answer in a code form. Trying to wrap my head around how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The third party limits me to 1000/call. Wonder if there is a way around it.

If there is a way around it, it is likely a bug in the third party's implementation and exploiting it will probably violate the terms of use, not a good idea as this will probably result in them preventing you from accessing their API.

If you really need all the information I can't think of another way other than making several calls in order to get all the information you need.